# How to mock a Path with several Attributes Names using Criteria API with Junit?

Tags: java, jpa, junit, criteria-api

I need to mock a Path of Criteria API to do tests with JUnit. The Path I want to mock is the following one:

`Path<Integer> idPath = transit.get("object1").get("object2").get("id");`

I have thought something like:

```
@Mock 
private Path<Integer> mockidPath;          
Mockito.when(mockTransitRoot.get("object1").get("object2").get("id"))
    .thenReturn(mockidPath);
```

But the error is:

> The method thenReturn(Path'Object') in the type OngoingStubbing is not applicable for the arguments (Path'Integer').

I have tried another way:

```
@Mock 
private Path<Object> mockidPath;
```

But it gives a NullPointerException Error.

Comment: You'd have to mock all the intermediate objects, which would be bad in many, many ways. You don't *need* to do what you're trying to do, you *want* to do it because you don't realize it's the wrong way to test. What is it that you're actually testing?

Comment: try this `Mockito.when(mockTransitRoot.get(any())
    .thenReturn(mockidPath1, mockidPath2, mockidPath3)`  you need to create two more mocks like mockidPath1. Each time get is called, one mock is returned. Finally mockidPath3 will be returned